# TNSPING response time

Tags: oracle, database-connectivity, tnsping

I am connecting to a 12c database from my client machine using 12c oracle client. Below is my TNS entry.

```
PLMDEV1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sesbexa3-scan2.exadata.ericsson.se)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PLMDEV1)
      (UR = A)
    )
  )
```

When i am doing the TNSPING from client machine to the database, i am getting the output as below.

```
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sesbexa3-scan2.exadata.ericsson.se)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = PLMDEV1) (UR = A)))
OK (20 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (10 msec)
OK (40 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (0 msec)
OK (20 msec)
OK (0 msec)
```

Can some one explain me what is this 0ms, 10ms,20ms,40ms means? If it is the over all time taken for client to establish connection with database, why i see different response times? Will this cause any performance issues to my client (while establishing connection to the DB)?

Answer (score 0):

Clear explanation in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/connect.htm#NETAG378).

> ... determines whether the listener for a service on an Oracle Net
>   network can be reached successfully ... then it displays **an estimate
>   of the round trip time** (in milliseconds) it takes to reach the
>   Oracle Net service.
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> - net_service_name must exist in tnsnames.ora file or the name service in use, such as NIS.
>
> - count determines how many times the program attempts to reach the server. This argument is optional.
> ```

No peformance issues in your posted test, but be aware:

> It **does not actually determine whether or not the database itself is
>   running**. Use SQL*Plus to attempt a connection to the database.

Finally:

**TNSPING tests connectivity to a service / listener, not to a server**, you can always try to check the listener log or restart it to check if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you. So, the 20/40 milliseconds that i see is time it takes to reach Oracle net service (On the server) through network, firewall(if exist).. what could be the factor that is giving the different response times?? is it Network? Is there a way to find it out?? When i do the traceroute to DB server, i am not getting 40 milliseconds response time any where, but TNSPING is showing 40 ms.. How can we justify this?

Comment: TNSPING tests connectivity to a service, not to a server. This might be the reason for the difference.

Comment: Thankyou.. Like traceroute shows the list of all intermediate hops it does to reach the server, is there any way to check all the intermediate layers/hops for TNSPING? this might give some understanding for that 40ms roundtrip time

Comment: TNSPING only test the connectivity against the Listener, there's no way to check intermediate layers. The time you’re getting seems quite right for me (traceroute is way more light in resource consumption) but you can always try to check the listener log or restart it to check if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you. Let me rephrase my question this way. Yes, i agree that TNSPING only checks the net service on DB server. Time shown against the tnsping is the roundtrip time. Client-->(tnsping)-->DB server(checks the net service/listener status --> responds back to client with status.  So, my client waits for 40 milliseconds to get the oracle net service status when he does a tnsping (right?) .. So now my client knows that the listener is up. He establishes a real connection to the database using tnsnames.ora. So, my client connection takes minumum 20 milliseconds to reach DB listener??

Comment: That’s completely right, we can guess that 20 ms is the time needed to establish the connection.

Comment: at the same time when i check the traceroute to the DB server, it is showing as 1.5 - 2 ms.. With this can i interpret that the remaining 18 ms is taken by the listener to decode my connection (like resolving the IPs)?  What i would like to know is, how to check if my listener is experiencing any load? How much time it is taking to resolve my connection and pass it to the actual database?

Comment: The reason for asking me this question is, some times when we are doing the TNSPING , we are getting a response time of 60070 and above. We have enabled the sqlnet traces and found below in the logs. Can you help me what is causing this connection delay. `nttcni: TImeout or Error on this socket
nttcni: exit
nttcon: exit
nserror: entry
nserror: nsres: id=0, op=65, ns=12535, ns2=12560; nt[0]=505, nt[1]=0, nt[2]=0; ora[0]=0, ora[1]=0, ora[2]=0
nsopen: unable to open transport
snsbitts_ts: entry
`